# Returning true or false in a custom function

Tags: mysql, functions

I have this mysql table schema

```
CREATE TABLE `nxt_records` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `tel_number` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `nxt_status` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

and this function

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION the_nxt (in_number VARCHAR(255)) RETURNS varchar
BEGIN 
 if (exists(select tel_number from nxt_records where tel_number = in_number ))then
return 'true';
else
return 'false';
end if;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

which i want to use inside this stored procedure

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE nxt()
BEGIN
if (the_nxt(44) = true)then

select 'found.';
else
select 'nothing found.';
end if;

END //
DELIMITER ;
```

when i run the function code,i get the error

> SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'BEGIN   if (exists(select tel_number from
>   nxt_records where tel_number = in_num' at line 2

What is causing this error?.

Comment: Note that `if (the_nxt(44) = true)` will **never** be true, because `the_nxt()` returns `VARCHAR 'true'` instead of the literal value `TRUE` (which is the integer 1)... and the string 'true' != the integer 1 (`true`, unquoted).  A more correct and less error-prone solution would be for the function to return a `TINYINT` TRUE or FALSE and test whether `the_nxt(44) IS TRUE` (not `=`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the error to have been my varchar

`CREATE FUNCTION the_nxt (in_number VARCHAR(255)) RETURNS varchar`

which i changed to

`CREATE FUNCTION the_nxt (in_number VARCHAR(255)) RETURNS varchar(255)` and worked.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

CREATE FUNCTION the_nxt (in_number VARCHAR(10)) RETURNS varchar(10)
BEGIN 
 if (exists(select tel_number from nxt_records where tel_number='in_number' ))
 then
return 'true';
else
return 'false';
end if;
END$$

Faced this error 
ERROR 1418 (HY000): This function has none of DETERMINISTIC, NO SQL, or READS SQL DATA in its declaration and binary logging is enabled (you *might* want to use the less safe log_bin_trust_function_creators variable)
 and use this
 SET GLOBAL log_bin_trust_function_creators = 1;

Regards,
Nawaz